# Pseudo classes not working

Tags: css

This should be an easy solve but I'm not sure why this is happening. I have a div with an id of `test` and inside that div, I have a paragraph tag with a link.

Currently, within the test class, the links are not visible and I don't understand why. I want a global pseudo class for links that I do not want anything special for. That should be be the code in the following 4 lines.

```
a:link {color:#000;text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {color:#000;text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {color:#000;text-decoration:none;}
a:active {color:#000;text-decoration:none;}
```

Where I do want to do something special, I can refer to the `#test` class as I have it below that the browser should only use that class within the `test` div and nowhere else. Am I incorrect on this?

```
#test p a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {color: #FFFFFF;}
```

FF shows me that test is being used outside of the test div. In other words, on a totally different page where test is not even used, I can see that the test class is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS does not work that way. You have to define #test for each one. Example:

```
#test p a:link, #test p a:visited, #test p a:hover, #test p a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Wow, OK, I guess I have to change this then. I'll give this a try now. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You're right Shaz, it works. When the SO timer expires, I'll credit you for the answer. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#test p a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {color: #FFFFFF;}
```

should be

```
#test p a:link, #test p a:visited, #test p a:hover, #test p a:active {color: #FFFFFF;}
```

You forgot to add the reference to the `test` div for each of the link pseudo classes

Comment: Thank you John. I'll change this and see what happens.